# Why doesn't frequency change on reflection from a surface?

Tags: visible-light, momentum, energy-conservation, reflection, frequency

If a beam of light is incident on a free to move reflecting surface the surface should gain some momentum in the opposite direction of the  reflected beam to conserve linear momentum and hence some energy is transferred to the surface in the process.
This energy has to come from the light and the light should get red shifted changing the frequency but I have read in numerous sources that frequency doesnt change on reflection.

Comment: Duplicate? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132515/

Comment: hint; taking the mass of the mirror which is usually fixed on a wall one can calculate/estimate the momentum transfer and see whether any imminent shift in  frequency of incident light  of observable  dimension comes up.